# Determine Monday and Friday code stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have entries in a database that I want to group by the week in which they occurred.  What I am trying to do is determine the week of the year that the entry occurred on, and then display the Week and the Monday and Friday of that week. This page http://princeave.com/bo/test.php shows the output that I am getting.  Notice that the Monday and Friday is correct for the events that occurred in  2017, but not for those in 2018.  The code is below.  What Am I missing?

```
<?php //Gets list of weeks that I can bill
    try {
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(transaction_date) AS YR, WEEK(bo_hourly_charges.transaction_date) as wk FROM bo_hourly_charges WHERE billed_by='AfterCare' ORDER BY transaction_date DESC");
        $stmt2->execute();
         // set the resulting array to associative
         $result2 = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $count = $stmt2->rowCount();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<div align='center'>

<br>
        <?php 
            foreach (($stmt2) as $row) { 
                $fix = $row['YR']."W".$row['wk'];
                $monday=date('M d',strtotime($fix));
                $friday=date('M d',strtotime($fix.'5'));
                print $fix." ".$row['wk']." ".$monday."-".$friday."<br>";
                ++$i;
             }
        ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps it is the `strtotime($fix)`, since I cannot file any reference to the yyyyWnn format here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php But that is just a wild guess. Oh, stop, I found it! :-) It is a compound format. It dus suggest to use a `-` (dash) before the 5 of Friday, perhaps it is that? I might not be able to distinguish between 15 and 15 when it has to be 15 and 1-5. Clearly I have no clue... sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, I wasn't aware PHP allowed that format. I don't believe it's documented behaviour. As such it might not be wise to rely on it.

[Running your code with the full range of weeks in 2017](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c76d0232f8730104c404bf39df71bd32459a8178) quickly showed the problem is not related to the year 2018:

```
<?php

$dates = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++) {
    $dates[] = ['YR' => 2017, 'wk' => $i];
}

foreach ($dates as $row) { 
    $fix = $row['YR']."W".$row['wk'];
    $monday=date('M d',strtotime($fix));
    $friday=date('M d',strtotime($fix.'5'));
    print $fix." ".$row['wk']." ".$monday."-".$friday."\n";
    ++$i;
}
```

Yields:

```
(...)
2017W5 5 Dec 31-Dec 31
2017W6 6 Dec 31-Dec 31
2017W7 7 Dec 31-Dec 31
2017W8 8 Dec 31-Dec 31
2017W9 9 Dec 31-Dec 31
2017W10 10 Mar 06-Mar 10
2017W11 11 Mar 13-Mar 17
2017W12 12 Mar 20-Mar 24
2017W13 13 Mar 27-Mar 31
2017W14 14 Apr 03-Apr 07
(...)
```

Instead, it seems the first nine weeks of 2017 have a similar problem. Starting in week 10, the problem seems resolved.

The difference between weeks 1 to 9 and weeks 10 and up, is closely related to the formatting.

[Padding the weeks with a zero](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c6f95a3ce5f3e1a41c162e207982474a09afa84) seems to resolve the problem:

```
<?php

$dates = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++) {
    $dates[] = ['YR' => 2017, 'wk' => $i];
}

foreach ($dates as $row) { 
    $fix = $row['YR']."W".str_pad($row['wk'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $monday=date('M d',strtotime($fix));
    $friday=date('M d',strtotime($fix.'5'));
    print $fix." ".$row['wk']." ".$monday."-".$friday."\n";
    ++$i;
}
```

The wiser choice, however, would be to use a more common date format.

Comment: Please post your code inline, so we don't need to click a link.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am a novice, so I am learning from you!

Answer (score 2):

As per [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php), the correct compound date for `ISO year with ISO week and day` is defined as follows:

```
YY "-"? "W" W "-"? [0-7]
```

where dashes (`-`) are optional (this is the meaning of the question mark `?` appended right after them). Hence, nothing is wrong in your format... but what happens with your code is that, for example, `2018W4` (4th week of 2018) becomes `2018-W45` (45th week of 2018) and everything gets messed up. In order avoid ambiguous formats, make sure that your week number always contains `two digits` (from `01` to `53`) by zero padding it:

```
$fix = $row['YR'].'W'.sprintf('%02d',$row['wk']);
```

On a side note, if you want to use prepared SQL statements, you should avoid manually inserting the parameters in the query. Otherwise you will make vain one of the main purposes of this approach: the safety.

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(transaction_date) AS YR, WEEK(bo_hourly_charges.transaction_date) as wk FROM bo_hourly_charges WHERE billed_by=? ORDER BY transaction_date DESC");
$stmt2->bind_param('s','AfterCare');
```

Comment: The issue is only that `W` has always to be two digits (`"0"[1-9] | [1-4][0-9] | "5"[0-3]`). `-` doesn't matter.